# Need help in date using moment js ( 2015-06-02T00:00:00Z)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to fetch the video data from YouTube API. 
This is my request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={{YOUKEY}}&channelId={{CHANNELID}}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2014-09-21T00:00:00Z&publishedBefore=2014-09-22T02:00:00Z
```

As you can see in this, the `publishedAfter` is in this way
`2014-09-21T00:00:00Z` with time set to zero. I tried using `moment`, but couldn't get the exact format.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the format you're aiming for?

Comment: what is the code you are writing

Comment: @elad.chen I am aiming for this format

2014-09-21T00:00:00Z with time set to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default `moment.format()` Date is displayed like you ask, however you could force it by using a format string like

```
moment(string).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z]');
```

explanation

- `YYYY` year in digits
- `MM` month in digits (base 1)
- `DD` day of year in digits
- `T` a random letter
- `hh:mm:ss` hour:minutes:seconds
- `[Z]` escape sequence for printing the letter `Z`

the letter `Z` in the format string in fact prints the [time zone,](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) as seen in the docs.

the exact solution is

```
var formatString = 'YYYY-MM-DDT[00:00:00Z]';

moment(string).format(formatString);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2pchp7b/)

Comment: thanks for the explanation but I need the result after formatting to be like this  2014-09-21T00:00:00Z , in the fiddle which you have given it gives the output as 2014-09-21T05:30:00Z

Comment: in my solution I wrote how to escape chars

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand your solution